# VBscript. Имя Excel файла с текущей датой и временем

Tags: excel, vbscript

есть код который формирует "Отчет" в Excel. Необходимо сделать чтобы имя файла сохранялось с текущей датой и временем. Так же пробовал, создавать просто таблицу, а потом сохранять в директорию. Не совсем понятно, что я делаю не так.
В основном пользовался:

1. [Open an Excel file and save as .XLS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17464698/open-an-excel-file-and-save-as-xls)
2. [Need VBS code to saveas xlsm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39429373/need-vbs-code-to-saveas-xlsm)
3. [VBScript to Open an Excel File and then do a Save As](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35132469/vbscript-to-open-an-excel-file-and-then-do-a-save-as)
4. [How to Add Date and Time To File Name Using VBA in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20635629/how-to-add-date-and-time-to-file-name-using-vba-in-excel)

Собственно фрагмент кода:

````
```  Dim objExcel, activeWB, activeSheet,objWorkbook,Storage_Path
    Dim tp, strPath, Fn
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Storage_Path = "D:\Stat\" 
    Fn = Format(CStr(Now), "yyyy_mm_dd_hh_mm_ss_")
    tp = ".xlsx"
    strPath = Storage_Path&Fn&tp
    objExcel.Visible = False
    
    Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add ()
    'objExcel.workbooks.SaveAs SaveDateTime(String)
    'Save and quit.
    objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs (strPath)
    objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
    objExcel.Application.Quit
    'objExcel.workbooks.SaveAs "D:\Stat\1.xlsx"
    'objExcel.workbooks.close
    'objExcel.quit
    'Set objExcel = Nothing
    Set objExcel = Nothing 
End Sub   '''
````

Comment: Добро пожаловать в SO! Извини, но не понял - в описании проблемы говоришь "чтобы имя файла сохранялось", а в коде пишешь "чтобы имя файла открывалось"... А как оно откроется, если ты это имя вот только сейчас сформировал? Нет ещё такого файла...

Comment: Извиняюсь, просто я в этом новичок. Сейчас постараюсь подправить, действительно

Comment: Ну, так получше... Книга сохраняется в нужном месте с нужным именем? Осталось разобраться, что за зверь `items`, откуда взялся и что содержит

Comment: Книга не сохраняется, в этом и проблема. Если указать на прямую путь и имя файла то сохраняется, к примеру objExcel.workbooks.SaveAs "D:\Stat\1.xlsx". Тогда работает. А когда указываешь, через переменную тогда уже не сохраняется

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка связана с неправильным использованием **[Format](https://forum.ixbt.com/topic.cgi?id=26:34624:2#2)**

Рабочий код:

```
Function FormatDateYYYYMMDD(D)
    FormatDateYYYYMMDD = Year(D) & "_" & Format2DigitString(Month(D)) & "_" & Format2DigitString(Day(D))
End Function

Function FormatDateYYYYMMDDHHMMSS(D)
    FormatDateYYYYMMDDHHMMSS = FormatDateYYYYMMDD(D) &  "_" & Format2DigitString(Hour(D)) &  "_" & Format2DigitString(Minute(D)) &  "_" & Format2DigitString(Second(D))
End Function

Function Format2DigitString(N)
    If N >= 10 Then
        Format2DigitString= Format2DigitString & N
    Else
        Format2DigitString= Format2DigitString & "0" & N
    End If
End Function

    Dim objExcel, activeWB, activeSheet,objWorkbook,Storage_Path
    Dim tp, strPath, Fn
    Storage_Path = "F:\Test\" 
    Fn = FormatDateYYYYMMDDHHMMSS(Now)
    tp = ".xlsx"
    strPath = Storage_Path & Fn & tp
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    objExcel.Visible = False
    
    Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add ()
' Здесь что-то написать в новую книгу:
    objWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value = "Эта новая книга будет сохранена в " & strPath
    objWorkbook.SaveAs (strPath)
    objWorkbook.Close
    objExcel.Application.Quit
 
    Set objExcel = Nothing
```

Comment: Спасибо, а как? до этого дойти. Где бы это почитать? Интересно. Спасибо, огромное

Comment: Даже не знаю, что посоветовать... При запуске твоего варианта скрипта выскакивало сообщение *"Ошибка выполнения Microsoft VBScript: Несоответствие типа: 'Format'"*. Поиск по этому тексту вывел на сообщение 14-летней давности, ссылку на которое я дал в своём ответе (правда, функции от Осипова были добавлены туда 9 лет назад, но это уже не существенно)

Comment: Простите, а вы использовали Visual Studio ?  для компиляции скрипта

Comment: Да нет, студию себе и не ставил никогда. Так, в FAR'е код набросал, через cscript  выполнил. Разве VS может больше?

Comment: Да нет, просто ради интереса